# $W_0^{k,p}(\Omega)\subseteq W_0^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ via zero extention

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $W_0^{k,p}(\Omega)$ denote the closure of all testfunctions with compact support in $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$.

Would it be right to identify any function in $u\in W_0^{k,p}(\Omega)$ as a function in
$u\in W_0^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ when identifying $u$ with its zero extention (only in one direction) such that $W_0^{k,p}(\Omega)\subseteq W_0^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$?

I think yes, and can provide a proof for, but I'm interested in your independent opinion to exclude wether I made a mistake or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, since $u\in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ has zero trace, you can extend it by zero in $\mathbb{R}^d\setminus\Omega$ to obtain a function $\tilde{u}\in W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $\tilde{u} = u$ in $\Omega$ and $\tilde{u} = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^d\setminus\Omega$. The proof of the integrability is straightforward, while for the weak differentiability take any $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Then
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\tilde{u}\partial^\alpha\phi\,dx = \int_\Omega u\partial^\alpha\phi\, dx = (-1)^{\vert\alpha\vert} \int_\Omega \partial^\alpha u \phi\,dx = (-1)^{\vert\alpha\vert}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}v\phi\, dx$$
for all multiindices $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^d_0$ such that $\vert\alpha\vert\leq k$, where
$$ v = \begin{cases} \partial^\alpha u, &&\text{in } \Omega, \\
0, &&\text{in } \mathbb{R}^d\setminus\Omega.
\end{cases}$$
Note that the space is $W^{k,p}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\textbf{not}$ $W^{k,p}_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$, as the latter isn't defined.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But what do you mean by $W^{k,p}\neq W^{k,p}_0$? I thought there the same when we take the whole space.

Comment: If you take the whole space there is no suitable definition of a trace operator, so it doesn't really make sense to define $W^{k,p}_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Comment: I see what you mean, but we can still define it. Anyway you helped me alot, by confirming that the thought is true.

Comment: Why was this question closed? Additional context missing? You mean like these questions with +50 votes with no context?

Comment: @Furkan I don't know, I didn't close it.

Comment: I think the reason it is closed is the question may be not be clear due to trace undefined for $\mathbb{R}^d$ domain. If you want to improve it, you can define that trace in some way, then it will be much more clear. One possible but naive way is to treat $\mathbb{R}^d$ as the limit of a sequence of domains. So you can define the extension naturally.